# Is there any way of scripting or workflowing file names of files uploaded in Netsuite?

Tags: drag-and-drop, workflow, filenames, netsuite, suitescript

This particularly relates to files created in Drag and Drop functionality, but applies to any file uploaded.
Is it possible to use a workflow or script to create a naming convention, such as `{internalID}+{date}`, so that all files uploaded are named automatically to refer to the record they are attached to?

Comment: I'm not sure about catching them as they are uploaded, but you can schedule a script to grab files that have recently been uploaded, and edit the names of those files.  Not sure if that would help you or not, though.

Comment: That could do the trick, as long as the script ran fairly regularly... I'm not too good with scheduled scripts though - what do you recommend?

Comment: In that case, I would just run a script that looks for any files created since the last run, that do not match the desired format.  Then update the filename.  I don't currently have access to a NetSuite environment to provide examples, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function and I just send as parameter the name of the file

```
 function createfile( content, fileName) {
```

`var fileObj = null,
        fileObj = file.create( {
            name:        fileName+ '.json',
            fileType:    file.Type.PLAINTEXT,
            contents:    content,
            description: 'TEST FILE .JSON',
            encoding:     file.Encoding.UTF8,
            folder:       57,
            isOnline:     true
        });
    return fileObj.save();
}`